# Error after created new c++ console application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

When I create new c++ console application (with MFC checkbox checked) in VS2010 I have a lot of errors during compilation connected with `prsht.h`, `zmouse.h`, `commctrl.h`.

I did **not** change anything in this file so I have not idea what is wrong. What are this files and how I can compile program without errors?

Few of the many errors (113)

> Error  13  error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\prsht.h 97  1   qwert
>
> Error  10  error C2065: 'CALLBACK' : undeclared identifier c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\prsht.h 97  1   qwert
>
> 19  IntelliSense: expected a ';'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\commctrl.h  165 21
>
> Error  2   error C2433: 'HWND' : 'inline' not permitted on data declarations   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft sdks\windows\v7.0a\include\zmouse.h    141 1   qwert

Comment: So using VS2010, I created a empty Visual C++ Console application, and checked "MFC Headers".  I got a very basic shell that compiles fine.  Did you add anything more to the project?  Be sure you are not using any of the VS Express Editions.

Answer (score 1):

You can try including the below in stdafx.h file before the #include "targetver.h" statement

```
#include "Winsock2.h"
#include "Windows.h"

#include "targetver.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

These errors happened, because compiler treats symbols `CALLBACK`, `HWND`, etc. as new, it does not know them.
These symbols are defined in `windows.h` header file.
So the diagnosis is: `windows.h was not included`.
This can happen because of ruined SDK files, so you need to reinstall your SDK.

On my computer the header files are included in the following chain: 
`stdafx.h - afxwin.h - afx.h - afxver_.h - afxv_w32.h - windows.h`, `zmouse.h`, `commctrl.h`

You can not include `windows.h` explicitly (as it was suggested before), because `afxv_w32.h` file has the following lines at the beginning:

```
#ifdef _WINDOWS_
    #error WINDOWS.H already included.  MFC apps must not #include <windows.h>
#endif
```

You can take a look at this: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/fff0ebaa-5153-40b9-89cf-cb9661abb2a4/

Answer (score 0):

You may not cancelled the define code generated by VS:
(in framework.h)

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
```

This define command told complier not include some specific headers like Windows. You may forgot to check the MFC support when creating the project.

After comment the #define, it may help.